# Fade out na div mãe mas não nos seus filhos com jQuery

Tags: jquery, transição

Eu tenho este código, mas gostaria que a `#navBar` sofresse o *fadeOut*, `#menuBt` e `#hi` ficassem sempre visíveis, é possível?

HTML:

```
<div id="navBar">
    <div id="hi"></div>
    <div id="menuBt"><h3>menu</h3></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#navBar').stop().fadeOut(500);
```

Comment: Acho que só tirando de dentro do `#navBar`.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%c3%adtulo/1911#1911

Answer (score 3):

A única forma de fazer isso é retirando os nós internos ao `navBar` de dentro do `navBar`. Uma forma é adicioná-los após o `navBar` quando a animação terminar:

```
$('#navBar').stop().fadeOut(500,function(){
  $(this).after($(this).children());
});
```